# Converting c to c# (libvlc method using smem)

Tags: c#, c, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to convert the C code here:
http://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_to_memory_(smem)_tutorial
to C# for an open source project (ispy).

My main problem at the moment is converting the method signature:

`void handleStream(void* p_audio_data, uint8_t* p_pcm_buffer, unsigned int channels, unsigned int rate, unsigned int nb_samples, unsigned int bits_per_sample, unsigned int size, int64_t pts )`

into a C# equivalent. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a *callback*, meaning that the C code has to call it. How you will implement this depends on how the rest of the code works.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a callback, I would make it a C# [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public delegate void handleStream (byte[] p_audio_data, uint[] p_pcm_buffer, 
                                   uint channels, uint rate, uint nb_samples, 
                                   uint bits_per_sample, uint size, ulong pts);
```

Comment: It's not clear how this would work. How will the interop code know how big those arrays are?

Comment: doesn't work - I'm pretty sure that void* p_audio_data should translate to IntPtr p_audio_data, not byte[] (as it's a pointer).

Also there's another method:
void prepareRender (void* p_audio_data, uint8_t** pp_pcm_buffer , unsigned int size)

That I have to translate to c# - I think uint8_t translates to byte[] but dunno how to handle the ** - is that a pointer to a pointer? My c is very rusty...

Comment: @Sean, `byte[]` *is* a pointer, and it points to an array. `uint8_t` is a `byte` in C#. @Gabe, you have the number of samples, the rate (samples/sec/channel) and the number of channels, so you know how large the audio data should be. If anything, you have *too much* information.

Comment: void* p_audio_data can actually translate to void* p_audio_data in c#. I think uint8_t** is a pointer to a pointer and so requires some marshalling...

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET wrapper for libvlc at http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/, you should probably use that and let it handle the details of P/Invoke.

Comment: Using a prewritten wrapper is a great idea, but do you know that the OP's task is actually handled by that library?

Comment: It doesn't - and yeah i'm using the nVLC wrapper library, which doesn't do this either :(

Comment: @Sean: You have to post a description (or a link to it) of how the callback is supposed to work in order for us to figure out the proper declaration of it.

Comment: I thought i had in the first post:
 [link](http://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_to_memory_(smem)_tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Also there is [Vlc.DotNet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com)

The project have Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops library which provide VLC interops for all versions of VLC >= 1.1